# How to add font-face in storybook in nx app?

Tags: css, reactjs, storybook, nrwl-nx, nrwl

My app is built using React and NX. I am trying to add `@font-face` in storybook using `preview-head.html` file.
This is my font-face.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Switzer-Regular';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Switzer-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../assets/fonts/Switzer-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../assets/fonts/Switzer-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This is my `preview-head.html`

```
<style>
  * {
    font-family: 'Switzer-Regular';
    src: url('fonts/Switzer-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('fonts/Switzer-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('fonts/Switzer-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: normal;
  }
</style>
```

After running this code snippet my storybook was able to capture the `font-family`, `font-weight`, `font-style` But `src` and `font-display` says it is unknown property name.

I tried exploring NX storybook [docs](https://nx.dev/packages/storybook). But could not find any working solution. Any help would be appreciated !

Screenshot from dev tools(elements):
[image: Screenshot from dev tools(elements)]

Comment: https://mushti-dev.medium.com/hey-e6faa20b910a 
Please try this.